# Does the decay rate of singular values reflect linear dependency of vectors in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, svd

In order to compare two matrices, suppose A and B, based on the level of linear dependency between column vectors of a given matrix, I can think about following measures:

1. Rank of a matrix: If the rank of matrix A is higher than the rank of matrix B, this implies that the matrix B has more dependent columns than matrix A.

The measure based on the rank of a matrix works well if few of the singular values of a matrix are close to zero. This is not an appropriate measure if singular values do not decay to zero or slowly decay to zero for example for an ill-conditioned matrix.

2. The determinant of a matrix: The determinant of a matrix signifies the volume spanned by the columns of a matrix. The higher the volume, more independent the vectors are (assuming each column is normalized).

The measure based on the determinant of a matrix seems to appropriate for ill-conditioned matrix where determinant is simply the product of eigenvalues.

3. Now, a third measure based on intuition, i.e., the decay rate of singular values:
   Faster the decay, more dependent are the columns of a matrix.

Suppose the largest singular values of matrix A and matrix B are same. If the singular value decay of matrix B is faster than of the matrix A. The product of singular values for matrix B is lower than for the matrix A. This is equivalent to say that the determinant of matrix B is lower than the matrix A and therefore columns of the matrix B are more dependent than the matrix A.

But, I can not come up with a proper mathematical justification for the claimed third measure for any two matrices.

Does the third measure make sense to you for a general case? Can you think of a case where the third measure fails?

Comment: Take two diagonal invertible matrices. Their columns are perfectly linear independent, but all your measures fail to recognise them as similar

Comment: @Exodd You are right, if we think the usual meaning of linear dependency, i.e. can we express a column of a matrix as a linear combination of other columns of a matrix? Suppose, if we take two ill-conditioned square matrices where singular values decay to zero slowly, probably we will say that the numerical rank of these matrices are same. But, can we directly infer the columns of these two matrices are independent in the same order of magnitude? In two-dimension, I relate the order of magnitude with the angular gap between the two vectors.

Comment: If you normalize the columns first, you can take $\|A^TA-I\|$ as a good measure for non-independece, since it represents, more or less, the angular gap between all vectors

Comment: @Exodd If a matrix is diagonal, invertible and the columns are normalised, you get $+-1$ on the diagonal ... However, I like your idea of using $A^TA$

Comment: @Exodd Cool. I like the idea as well. Thanks for the pointer.